# The Other Side of CAPTCHA

Tags: authentication, theory

CAPTCHA stands for "Completely Automated Public Turing Test to Tell Computers and Humans Apart", but we only consider one half of it i.e. a test to separate genuine humans from bots.

Can a program/test exist that can be only "solved" by computers/bots and not by humans?

If not, what prevents such a program from existing in the foreseeable future?

If it does, could you please cite it and how it works?

**Here I'm not considering the practicability of such a service.This is a hypothetical scenario** (so it's not limited to the internet) **where an external program must be able to tell the difference by exploiting something that only computers can do.**

The program can't state something like *multiply these 50 digit numbers together* as this could be broken by someone like [Shakuntala Devi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shakuntala_Devi).
I'm looking for a concrete test/method that prevents humans from solving such a program within the next 20 years.

Comment: On your marks, get set.... multiply 8265168415 by 8765741387. Time's up!

Comment: Is there a use case for a CAPTCHA that blocks non-computers?

Comment: @FireQuacker I thought of mentioning that you can't use a test that depends on computational abilities but I thought that it seemed to be obvious :)

Comment: Well if such a test exists, what prevents a bot from solving the _CAPTCHA_ and then handing over the session to the human user?

Comment: What abilities do `computers` have, other than `computational` abilities?

Comment: I'm not seeing a security angle to this, even though you tagged it `authentication`

Comment: This was actually an interesting question, also somehow related to security. The question could be interpreted as: why CAPTCHAS test humans and check for human capabilities, instead of the other way around? And I don't think the answer is really obvious. IMO, in short, the answer is that on the internet, remotely, the test cannot be forced without consent. In other words, a human or a bot will have to perform an action. But only the human has an interest in being tested, and pass the test. Why would a bot want to be tested? It will refuse. So you end up only checking the human.

Comment: @reed actually, some ctf include such tests, to ensure that the answer has been automated and not performed manually, such as "provide me the password buried in a 500-level depth zip file".

Comment: @nobody By that I meant that you can't exploit the gap in the number of calculations a computer can do compared to humans,because if such a program were to have a 100% success rate,I feel that it would lock out a vast number of computers that are not new-age.Such a test should be reverse-compatible.

Comment: @schroeder There isn't any other site that seems suitable,so I hope you take a look at it again.I'd suggest that you put in the correct tags as this doesn't seem to fit into any of them.

Comment: @reed I didn't understand your last statement.Why wouldn't a bot want to be tested?

Comment: Just because there isn't another site doesn't mean that this is the correct site. What's the security angle? https://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be interested since it's theoretical computer science.

Comment: @AlanWhitteaker, I mean that since we are talking about security, bots are the threat to the humans, not the other way around. So a malicious bot will not want to be tested.

Comment: @reed "bots are the threat to the humans, not the other way around" I'm going to have to frame that :)

Comment: Interesting question, but I disagree that your multiplication question can be broken by humans. It took Devi 28 seconds to multiply two 13 digit numbers. This is amazing, but not even approaching the speeds of a computer that would take less than a millisecond to calculate it. It would take a human longer to type out the answer than it would for a computer to calculate and submit a million of these calculations. So I think asking for multiplication or division of 100 pairs of 50+ digit numbers would prove it's a computer  based on the speed of the response.